# Table-name.column-name in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plsql

I would like to use the following syntaxis in my PL/pgSQL code:

```
INSERT INTO table (table.column1, table.column2) VALUES (1, 2);
```

But somehow it doesn't work. Does anybody know if such a notation it is prohibited or I do something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, if you really want to use the name `table` for your table then you will need to enclose it in quotes:

```
create table table (column1 integer, column2 integer);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "table"

create table "table" (column1 integer, column2 integer);
CREATE TABLE
```

but assuming your table name is something different (which I highly recommended), the error returned indicates that the parser is interpreting `my_table` as a column name:

```
create table my_table (column1 integer, column2 integer);
CREATE TABLE

insert into my_table (my_table.column1, my_table.column2) values (1, 2);
ERROR:  column "my_table" of relation "my_table" does not exist
```

This interpretation is sensible, as `column1` may be a [composite type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/rowtypes.html), for example:

```
create type my_type as (column1 integer, column2 integer);
create table my_table (col my_type);
insert into my_table (col.column1, col.column2) values (1, 2);
select * from my_table;

  col
-------
 (1,2)
(1 row)
```

You probably just want the following as already suggested by DrColossos:

```
insert into table (column1, column2) values (1, 2);
```

Comment: I see the trick you've suggested. Very nice, but how it may influence overall perfomance? Anyway, I asked this question because I just started to use Navicat app for working with PostgreSQL from my Mac. So, in Navicat code autocompletion works properly with table-name.column-name way... Strange thing indeed.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you use composite types, just trying to explain why the parser interprets your syntax a certain way. It sounds like the question has arisen because of a quirk of Navicat - that sort of autocompletion makes sense in a `select` statement but not in the column list on an `insert` statement. Maybe you should let Navicat know there is a bug in their software?

Comment: Hi Jack, for sure. I just have to fid out how I submit a new ticket for them :-)

Comment: Seems that Navicat is not about acepting client's feedback: http://www.navicat.com/en/support/support_ticket/submit_ticket.html

Answer (score 2):

`table.column1` can be confused with a [schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/ddl-schemas.html) lookup. It thinks that it needs to look for a schema named table.

Be sure to check out the docs on how to [create a schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-CREATE).  It says, that

> [..] the even more general syntax
>
> `database.schema.table`

This would also make no syntactical sense since you already know what table you are referring to. IF you need to query the schema, you would write it.

```
INSERT INTO your_schema.table (column1, column2) VALUES (1, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reference. Now I can say: Now I know for sure!